# Typescript Generic Promise Return Type

Tags: typescript, generics, promise, typescript-generics

Basically I'm trying to implement a function that always returns a fulfilled promise of the same "type" i pass to the function as a parameter

So if I call with a boolean it returns a fulfilled Promise, if I call with a string parameter it returns a fulfilled Promise and so on..

what I tried so far:

```
const PromiseOK = <T>(val: T): Promise<T> => {
    return Promise.resolve(val);
};
```

I don't know if it's the proper way to do it and in any case it breaks if i try to get a Promise< void >

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You implementation seems fine, the problem with void is that the parameter is still expected. You could call it with `undefined`

```
const PromiseOK = <T>(val: T): Promise<T> => {
    return Promise.resolve(val);
};

PromiseOK<void>(undefined)
```

A better option might be to use overloads to get special behavior for void:

```
function PromiseOK(): Promise<void>
function PromiseOK<T>(val: T): Promise<T>
function PromiseOK<T>(val?: T): Promise<T> {
    return Promise.resolve(val);
};

PromiseOK() // Promise<void>
PromiseOK(1) //Promise<number>
```

It is possible to have overloads with arrow functions, but the syntax is not exactly pretty :

```
const PromiseOK: {
    (): Promise<void>
    <T>(val: T): Promise<T>
} = <T>(val?: T): Promise<T> => Promise.resolve(val);

PromiseOK() // Promise<void>
PromiseOK(1) //Promise<number>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I like the idea of using overloads, is it possible to use overloads with the arrow notation?

Comment: @Plastic yes yo can (edited the answer), but the syntax is not exactly great ... I would stick with regular functions for overloads if you don't need the capture `this` behavior

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Hi, I am wondering if it possible to use the generic type in the function? Like `public promiseOK<T>(endpoint: string, returnType: T): Promise<T> {
        const promise: Promise<returnType>...` returnType is unknown here. `cannot find name returnType`. I am trying to make a generic wrapper-function. How can I make Promise take it as an argument?

Comment: @Joel the type parameter represents the type of `returnType` you should use that : `Promise<T>` will work fine in the body of the function.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I have asked a question recently where I am explaining a bit more what I am after. Do you mind taking a look? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The OP is looking to match the Type of the parameter and return value.

However, if you are looking for a truly generic promise for which the return type is dynamically set by the caller, use this.

```
const foo = <T>(bar: Bar): Promise<T> => {
  return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
    // resolve to anything you want that has type T
    // e.g. API response: T
  });
};

// Usage
foo<YourType>(someValueForBar).then().catch();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this

```
function PromiseOK<T>(val: T): Promise<T> {
    return Promise.resolve(val);
};
```

If you want to keep the fat arrow notation, then

```
const PromiseOK = <T extends any>(val: T): Promise<T> => {
    return Promise.resolve(val);
};
```

The notation `T extends any` also supports `void`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the thing is if i try to call as `PromiseOK()` the compiler says that the function expect one argument... it could be solved giving `val` as a optional parameter??

Comment: @Plastic Yes, it can be solved like that. But then the function would make no sense?